# How to parse individual variables from python code in case of multiple variables assignments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this simple python code example that parses a python code and extracts the variables assigned in it:

```
import ast
import sys
import astunparse
import json

tree=ast.parse('''\
a = 10
b,c=5,6
[d,e]=7,8
(f,g)=9,10
h=20
''',mode="exec")

for thing in tree.body:
    if isinstance(thing, ast.Assign):
        print(astunparse.unparse(thing).split('=')[0].strip())
```

I also tried a similar method with a NodeVisitor:

```
import ast
import sys
import astunparse
import json

tree=ast.parse('''\
a = 10
b,c=5,6
[d,e]=7,8
(f,g)=9,10
h=20
''',mode="exec")

class AnalysisNodeVisitor2(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Assign(self,node):
        print(astunparse.unparse(node.targets))
        
Analyzer=AnalysisNodeVisitor2()
Analyzer.visit(tree)
```

But both methods gave me this same [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVQ4L.png):

```
a
(b, c)
[d, e]
(f, g)
h
```

But the output I'm trying to get is individual variables like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each target is either an object with an `id` attribute, or a sequence of targets.

```
for thing in tree.body:
    if isinstance(thing, ast.Assign):
        for t in thing.targets:
            try:
                print(t.id)
            except AttributeError:
                for x in t.elts:
                    print(x.id)
```

This, of course, doesn't handle more complicated possible assignments like `a, (b, c) = [3, [4,5]]`, but I leave it as an exercise to write a recursive function that walks the tree, printing target names as they are found. (You may also need to adjust the code to handle things like `a[3] = 5` or `a.b = 10`.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I just tried it and I get "AttributeError: 'Assign' object has no attribute 'elts'" at the first assignment which is the a=10 so thing in my case has neither an id attribute nor elts attribute?

Comment: Sorry, I had a working test, then tried to reproduce it here from memory and completely forgot about the `targets` attribute. I'll update.

Comment: Thank you very helpful.